# How To Get Another Folder File In C# And Show In XML

Tags: c#, xml

i have a cod with this cod i can get files in my app folder but i want get another folder file too.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string[] files;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

            string folder = appPath;//Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\Archive\";
            string filter = "*.*";
            files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filter);

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            var root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Item"));

            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                var name = root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Name"));
                string string1 = item;
                string string2 = appPath;
                string result = string1.Replace(string2, "");
                name.InnerText = result;
                MessageBox.Show(result);
            }

            using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml", null))
            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                doc.Save(writer);
            }
            {

            }
        }
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Item>
  <Name>\data.xml</Name>
  <Name>\dataa.xml</Name>
  <Name>\WindowsFormsApplication9.exe</Name>
  <Name>\WindowsFormsApplication9.exe.config</Name>
  <Name>\WindowsFormsApplication9.pdb</Name>
  <Name>\WindowsFormsApplication9.vshost.exe</Name>
  <Name>\WindowsFormsApplication9.vshost.exe.config</Name>
  <Name>\WindowsFormsApplication9.vshost.exe.manifest</Name>
</Item>
```

i have 3 folder in my app folder too any folder i want any files in folders write in my xml .

Comment: What do you mean by another folder file?Folders in your local system?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list also the files in subfolders, instead of

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filter);
```

you can use

```
files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToArray();
```